# JSON dumped and reloaded fails to match the original structure

Tags: python, json

MCVE (with py.test)

```
import json 
def test_minimum():
            internal={}
            internal[0]=""
            external={}
            with open("source.json", 'w') as outfile:
                    json.dump(internal, outfile)
            with open('source.json', 'r') as f:
                    external = json.load(f)
            assert external == internal
```

I'm saving a json object to disk, loading it back in, and finding it doesn't match the original.  I suspect there's something going on with the unicode, but what's causing the error and what's the best way of dealing with it.

The error message is:

```
    assert external == internal
E           assert {'0': ''} == {0: ''}
E             Left contains more items:
E             {u'0': u''}
E             Right contains more items:
E             {0: ''}
E             Use -v to get the full diff
```

Comment: In JSON all keys are strings, so `json.dump` automatically converts your numbers to strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer and float keys are implicitly converted to strings when serializing to json. This minimal example clarifies it:

```py
>>> json.dumps({1: 2})
'{"1": 2}'

>>> json.dumps({'1': 2})
'{"1": 2}'
```

Obviously, two different Python objects are mapped to the same JSON so you wouldn't be always able to round-trip it back.